# DetailView Page inheriting code from RowView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

1. I have a detailview page, and on top of it the title lable appears to be the title of the row i navigated from. I need to just not display anything in the navigationbar but the title appears and i dont know where to change it.
2. I also have a backbutton however if i use navigation.backbarbuttonItem then the title of the previous page appears on the button. I want the button to just have back on it. I created a button using leftbarbuttonItem but then the button cannot be styled to look like a backbutton (with one side pointed). It appears as just a rectangular button which i dont like.

Could anyone know how to adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number 1, you can just set the viewController title on viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear, lets say

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  self.title = @"";
}
```

For number 2, you can use this code to have the "Back" pointy button.

```
UIViewController *viewController = [UIViewController alloc] init];

// This code    
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:nil
                                                              action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```